# What is the advantage of having aromaticity in biological compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

I am studying aromaticity, and apparently, aromaticity is common in biological molecules, just like 6-member rings (relieve ring strain and angle strain). I was wondering: is it because aromaticity makes the compound more stable to prevent unwanted reactions/modifications?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I finally found something interesting. Tyrosine, phenylalanine, and tryptophan interacts with cation-pi interactions in proteins to stabilize secondary structures. They are also over-represented in protein binding sites.

Comment: Orthogonal mechanism that comes to mind : evolution tried random molecules -> lower energy / more stable molecules were more likely to be tried -> evolution disproportionately tried aromatic molecules -> biological compounds have lots of aromaticity.

Comment: Personally I don't think this is representative of anything. Of the 20 amino acids only 4 have aromatic rings.

Comment: Ah, well, as for why they are over-represented in binding sites, that's a different question (and pretty  interesting, too).

Comment: Pi-stacking between the aromatic nucleobases in DNA helps stabilize the double helix structure.

Comment: Relared - http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60055/pi-electron-stacking-how-does-it-work