# Dissociation energy of benzene dimer

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, energy, molecular-structure, decomposition

It is known that the benzene dimer has two stable structures, T-shaped ($\ce{C_{2v}}$) or parallel-displaced ($\ce{C_{2h}}$) structure.

Now the question is: does the dissociation energy ($\ce{D_0}$) $$\ce{(C_6H_6)_2 -> C_6H_6 + C_6H_6}$$ depends on the structures?
Or it is independent of the structures?

Comment: Of course it has to depend, at least a bit...

Comment: Of the three configurations mentioned by @rbw  the parallel-displaced is most likely to be the most stable.; see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60055/pi-electron-stacking-how-does-it-work/60095#60095 and you can calculate these for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you have three configurations to consider: t-shaped, parallel-displaced and sandwich. The dissociation energy depends on the configurations of the structures since they may interact differently. As the pi-pi interaction is directional, the different structures of the dimer interact differently.

Comment: I think it would best if you elaborate a bit. Don't leave answers that require clarification from the asker.