# Does ordered mesoporous carbon (for example, CMK-3) contain aromatic rings?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, carbon-allotropes

I'm studying the article [Synthesis of ordered mesoporous phenanthrenequinone-carbon via π-π interaction-dependent vapor pressure for rechargeable batteries](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4261180/), in which authors explain some properties of the resultant composite of phenanthrenequinone (PQ) and ordered mesoporous carbon CMK-3 by the $\pi-\pi$ stacking between these moieties.

While PQ obviously contains aromatic rings, does the ordered mesoporous carbon do? As far as I know, $\pi-\pi$ stacking is possible only between aromatic compounds.

**UPD1:** So I did several things to elaborate on this question.

First, I tried to figure out, how ordered mesoporous carbon is produced. In [this article](http://dns2.asia.edu.tw/~ysho/YSHO-English/1000%20WC/PDF/Adv%20Mat13,%20677.pdf) authors report on several ways therefor; most of those include pyrolysis of *hydro*carbons. Well, in my non-professional opinion, this means, that the product will contain hydrogen in some form. Thus, there will be hydrocarbons, including, probably, cyclic and aromatic (for example, pyrene is often a product of burning, as far as I know). Is this right?

Second, I tried to figure out whether it is in general necessary for $\pi$-stacking to have both compounds aromatic. [This answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60055/pi-electron-stacking-how-does-it-work/60095#60095) suggests, that not, but that p-orbitals are needed. Can anyone confirm, please? Also, in [this article](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/cr030093d) (still to be read) there should be some insights.

Third, I decided to check on the question what is $\pi-\pi$ stacking in general, by reviewing [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255765109_Rethinking_the_Term_Pi-Stacking). While I'm still in process of reading it, I've already understood, that there's a lot of confusion in this field since there is a variety of this interaction types; possibilities depend strongly on the molecules themselves and their surroundings. Am I wrong?

Fourth, I tried to track back one of the statements regarding multi-walled carbon nanotubes $\pi-\pi$-interacting with PQ from [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283780047_Molecular_properties_of_910-phenanthrenequinone_and_benzil) (nanotubes just seem to me somewhat more clear than CMK-3, the chemical formula of which I even don't know). This led to surprisingly branched and sad journey to several articles aged past to '70s, not in any of which the $\pi$-stacking was ever proven, but always assumed (I have a long report for myself on this journey, here it is, however, not the correct place to post it). Anyways, it's an ongoing literature research and I decided to make a pause when the amount of articles to check reached six.